# Semi-bounded operator implies semi-bounded sesquilinear form

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, functional-inequalities

So my question is quite simple:

If an operator (which corresponds to a sesquilinear form) is semi-bounded (from below) then the sesquilinear form is also semi-bounded (from below)?

I'm pretty sure that this is true, but I dont know the proof.

Comment: How do you define that an operator is semi-bounded from below? Normally this is done in terms of the associated sesquilinear form.

Comment: Oh of course, now I see it. Thanks!